# SUM over with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to sum over partition with distinct values from GameID column. It should be partitioned over CasinoID column, but it shouldn't sum up amounts with same GameID.
 This is what I am aiming for

| Date | CasinoID | GameID | Amount | TARGETAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 4 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 300 | 3300 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3 | 1000 | 4300 |
| 2023-01-07 | 1 | 3 | 500 | 3800 |
| 2023-01-10 | 1 | 1 | 500 | 3300 |

Below are results.

```
Sum(amount) over (partition by CasinoID order by cast(date as date)) as TARGETAMOUNT
```

| Date | CasinoID | GameID | Amount | TARGETAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1000 | 4300 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 4 | 2000 | 4300 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 300 | 4300 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3 | 1000 | 4300 |
| 2023-01-07 | 1 | 3 | 500 | 4800 |
| 2023-01-10 | 1 | 1 | 500 | 5300 |

Since those first four are from same day the TARGETAMOUNT is correct this way but I just showed at the above example to make it clearer what I was aiming for.
But like it is shown below it sums bottom 2 rows to TARGETAMOUNT instead of replacing the amount value from the same GameID.

```
Sum(amount) over (partition by CasinoID, GameID order by cast(date as date)) as TARGETAMOUNT
```

This doesn't produce wanted end result either:

| Date | CasinoID | GameID | Amount | TARGETAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 4 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 300 | 300 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2023-01-07 | 1 | 3 | 500 | 1500 |
| 2023-01-10 | 1 | 1 | 500 | 1500 |

Comment: Please read ; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why do you aggregate game 4 before game 2?

Comment: Thank you for the article and the heads up.

Comment: @MatBailie they are randomly there, but it doesn't matter since in the end they are on same date and I have to calculate all from that date to end result.

Comment: @lsj Are you saying you only care about the final sum? Or that you only care about the daily results? (please edit your question to replace the data with text so that I can copy it)

Comment: Is it me or are all three screenshots exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way of looking at it is that for each row you want to add the new amount, but also take away that game's previous amount.

You can get the previous amount with LAG() and then use SUM(amount - previous_amount).

```
CREATE TABLE moneys (
  game_date   DATE,
  casino_id   INT,
  game_id     INT, 
  amount      INT
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  moneys
VALUES
  ('2024-01-01', 1, 1, 1000),
  ('2024-01-01', 1, 4, 2000),
  ('2024-01-01', 1, 2,  300),
  ('2024-01-01', 1, 3, 1000),
  ('2024-01-07', 1, 3,  500),
  ('2024-01-10', 1, 1,  500),
  ('2024-01-11', 1, 1,  100)
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
WITH
  lagged AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (
      PARTITION BY casino_id, game_id
          ORDER BY game_date
    )
      AS previous_amount
  FROM
    moneys
)
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(amount - previous_amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY casino_id
        ORDER BY game_date, game_id
  )
FROM
  lagged
```

| game_date | casino_id | game_id | amount | previous_amount | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 300 | 0 | 1300 |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 3 | 1000 | 0 | 2300 |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 4 | 2000 | 0 | 4300 |
| 2024-01-07 | 1 | 3 | 500 | 1000 | 3800 |
| 2024-01-10 | 1 | 1 | 500 | 1000 | 3300 |
| 2024-01-11 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 500 | 2900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/frDajZMG)

Comment: That is exactly what I was aiming for. Thank you very much. I am sorry about that I couldn't post without images. I think I had right md format for my tables but still it said I need to format.

Comment: @lsj https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: This is a genius answer, I wish one could upvote it more than once

Comment: @DaleK accepted answer now. This was my first question so I was not familiar. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: @siggemannen I'm flattered